# Alert when new version of iOS app is available

Tags: ios, push-notification

Is there an open source library out there for presenting an in-app alert when a new version is available to download? Push notification would be a plus also.

Comment: I looked into this a while back and couldn't find anything, and it wasn't worth writing it myself from scratch.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[iVersion](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iVersion) sounds like the exact thing you are looking for. It works similar to Sparkle on Mac OSX where it consults a remote file on your website where you can bump the version number once Apple approves your app and shows a prompt to the user if their version is lower than the one specified on your server.

Comment: The latest version of iVersion is actually totally configuration / file hosting free. Although it still supports more advanced options, by default all you have to do is import 3 files into your xcode project, and literally nothing else. Really nice.

Comment: I wonder if there are any tools to integrate to alert users of a new app you have released.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another one https://github.com/jacobsologub/appdate, it just calls Apple's search API to check if a given app "you app" has an update.