# Checking Application API Version in XCode?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alert when new version of iOS app is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496640/alert-when-new-version-of-ios-app-is-available)

I need code that I can embedd into my project code so that every request from the application to server contains the API version in case my iPhone app gets a new update so it can notify the user to update the new version of the application.

Where should I add the code to check this and what line of code is needed for it. I am not getting the right procedure to follow.

Please Help,
Thank you.

Comment: ok michael .Thxs for the link.actually i am using my mobile and so it did not show me the links to similar questions like me.
thxs anyways mate.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

1. Just create the separate web-service on server side which have parameter as app version.
2. Set the global variable on server side which holds the latest version of the app.
3. Now, from your application, when app will be launched, then call this service with the parameter of api version used in the app. (this api version will be static, because you have done the code for same. And when you will update your app then you will change the api code yourself. Hope you understand).
4. Check the api version on server side, and if app api using latest version then return TRUE. And if api on app using lower version then return FALSE.
5. Now, in application, if web-service returns the FALSE then just inform the user by ALERT that, he is using the lower version of the api and download latest app to use the latest api.

Hope, you got an idea of what to do.

Cheers.