# Updating application based on server response

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, versioning

I would like to have my iOS application to check whether or not its server requests are going through, in order to register the number of users in a database based on which version of the API they're using.

I would then use these statistics to choose an appropriate time to roll out later versions of the application, and notify the users of the new release.

Would it be possible to get an example of the code required to perform these kinds of analytics?

Comment: ok Rob and JulesMazur....     i understand and appreciate your advice ... i have been looking for this for quite a while but didnot receive any solution i would be updating all the research done by me soon...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14017360/checking-application-api-version-in-xcode... and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496640/alert-when-new-version-of-ios-app-is-available....... but i am not looking for this solution now i have corrected my question in this post of actually what i intend to do..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496640/alert-when-new-version-of-ios-app-is-available and http://stuff.bondo.net/post/7769890357/using-build-and-version-numbers-and-the-art-of      .... whenever i search for similar solutions to my question i usually end up with this type of results as the link provided by me.... but actually i need something else as indicated in thwe question here above.please guide if i am wrong..

Comment: yes you are right ... i am using ASIHTTPRequest ... i have my database on the server ....